# Exception raised during rendering: action_bar

Tags: android

When I create a new project on android studio it is not giving any problem but I looking at the activity_main.xml design it is shows me this: "Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: action_bar".
I know how fix this problem,just list this issue [android studio sdk version 22 exception during rendering: action_bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034476/android-studio-sdk-version-22-exception-during-rendering-action-bar)

> But I want to know why this happens，some people know?

Answer (score 6):

ActionBar has been deprecated, it's better to use "Toolbar" and it gives a lot of features as well, as of API 21 ActionBar has been replaced by Toolbar because of which you are getting this error,

if you mention in your manifest file maxSDK required less than API 21 you will not get this error.

But still go with ToolBar it enables you to do things which you can do with a view

Comment: you are welcome :) check out material design, that would help you a lot