# How to change my android custom actionbar overflowbutton scale?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to change the image of actionbar overflow button, I've replaced a custom image on it by following code:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionItemOverflow</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionItemOverflow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/actionbar_add_icon</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">15dp</item>
</style>
```

but then the question is how to make the image's scale fit the actionbar? The attributes `android:scaleType`, `android:layout_width`, `android:layout_height`doesn't works

Comment: luffy try using Toolbar, action bar is deprecated, Toolbar provides a lot of customization options and it is pretty easy as you can treat Toolbar as a view as it extends ViewGruop  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202706/exception-raised-during-rendering-action-bar/29203378#29203378

Comment: Thank you:) I would try it again!